# Is it possible to use a delegate or generic for any void method?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I am trying to write an exception handler class that converts from types of EF exceptions to HttpStatusCodes.
I know how to handle the catching and sending the message to the ApiController.

```
public class ExceptionConverter : IExceptionConverter
{
    //need the parameter
    public HttpStatusCode Convert()
    {
        try
        {
            //call the void repository method here
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (exception is ObjectNotFoundException)
                return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            if (exception is InvalidOperationException)
                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
        return HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to write a Delagate or Generic method that could call my void repository methods.

I was thinking I could use an interface with the methods I use in my conversion

```
public interface IHandleCrudOperations
{
    //All of these methods need to be able to take in many different parameters
    //They will always need a parameter though
    void Remove();
    void Add();
    void Edit();
    void Clone();
}
```

As you can see I would need to be able to pass in a slew of different parameters based on the repository method in question:

```
//userRepository
public void Remove(int userKey)
{
    //stuff
}

//groupRepository
public void Remove(string groupName)
{
    //stuff
}

//someOtherRepository
public void Remove(RemoveSomethingRequest request)
{
    //stuff
}
```

I considered using a generic methods for this:

```
public interface IHandleCrudOperations
{
    //All of these methods need to be able to take in many different parameters
    //They will always need a parameter though
    void Remove<T>(T item);
    void Add<T>(T item);
    void Edit<T>(T item);
    void Clone<T>(T item);
}
```

Now the implementation gets difficult:

```
//userRepository
public void Remove<T>(T item)
{
    //SERIOUS code smell here
    var userKey = (int)(object)item
    _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserKey == userKey);
    //stuff
}

//groupRepository
public void Remove<T>(T item)
{
    //SERIOUS code smell here
    var groupName = (string)(object)item
    //stuff
}

//someOtherRepository
public void Remove<T>(T item)
{
    //SERIOUS code smell here
    var request = (RemoveSomethingRequest)(object)item
    //stuff
}
```

That has many bad flaws, readability, abusing generics, generally just bad, etc....

So, since all of the methods for this operation return void:

Is this possible with Delegates?
Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: I suspect that the code smell could be removed by rethinking the design more fundamentally.  How is the repository implemented and used?

Comment: @phoog Each type (ex. User, Group, Report, etc..) has a repository specific to its class. How we handle Crud operations cannot be unified because we sometimes need to Add/Edit/Remove a user by Kev, Name, or actual User object

Comment: Check my edited answer for another idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT looks to me like you have different types of keys: Users have an int key, and Groups have a string key.  So I'd make a generic interface whose methods don't have type parameters, like this:

```
interface IRepository<TItem, TKey>
{
    void RemoveItem(TItem item);
    void RemoveByKey(TKey key);
    void RemoveByName(string name);
}
```

The implementation should be clear from that, but if it isn't leave a comment.

EDIT: You could also do this, but only if TKey and TItem are never the same, and are never `string`:

```
interface IRepository<TItem, TKey>
{
    void Remove(TItem item);
    void Remove(TKey key);
    void Remove(string name);
}
```

Comment: That is true except I have A LOT of repositories with A LOT of Remove methods that take in different things to remove by. Could be int, string, myObject, yourObject, IEnumerable<int>

Comment: In that case, I think, your choices are to redesign the application (lots of work), live with the many overloads (messy), or abuse generics (also messy, and potentially a lot of work).

Comment: So this is a newb generic question I am sure, but why could it never be a string?

Comment: @Robert because then the Remove overloads would not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the generic parameter `T` to the interface itself:

```
public interface IHandleCrudOperations<TKey, T>
{
    void Remove(TKey item);
    void Add(T item);
    void Edit(T item);
    void Clone(T item);
}

public class UserRepository : IHandleCrudOperations<int, User>
{
    public void Remove(int userKey)
    {
        _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserKey == userKey);
        //stuff
    }

   public void Add(User user)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: The Add, Edit and Clone methods may not be integers in the same class

Comment: @Robert - You could add a type for the key if that's what you mean. Alternatively you could add an interface to the object type to specify the key.

Comment: This is good only problem I see is that I could not inject this into the ExceptionConverter class above. I would have to create an exception converter class for each repository